# Warning: mysql_result(). Unable to solve

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Im getting this Error:

Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Ive checked other questions on this and can't seem to find the answer. Any thoughts on it?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` == 1");
return(mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Remove the `' '` from `username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query should be, you used `'` around column name, you have to surround the it with `` ` ``

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

change this

```
`active` == 1");
```

to

```
`active` = 1");
```

Comment: Im not sure what is different about it?

Comment: I don't see a downvote

Comment: One is the regular apostrophe, the other is the ` mark on the tilde key.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your query won't work is because your are wrapping the column name and table name with single quotes. They are identifiers and not string literals so they shouldn't be wrap with single quote.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'
```

If it happens that the column names and tables names used are a reserved keyword, they can be escape with backticks not with single quotes.

In this case, the backticks aren't required since none of them are reserved keywords.

Other links:

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)
- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: +1 for precise explanation

Comment: Im very sorry about this but I am now receiving the warning on a different line but changed it according to the other one. Would you be kind enough to look at that one? Its above

Comment: the problem is here `active == 1`, it should be `active = 1`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php :: you should never parse a variable directly into a sql statement to avoid sql injections

Comment: what's missing on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct way of escaping column use backtick operator if you wish to like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```